# Connecting Window with ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I have following code

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="UI/ResourceDirectory.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainWindowViewModel}">
            <local:MainWindow></local:MainWindow>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>
```

And it is giving following error

> Can't put a window in a Style

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9c0f0a25-81e3-4482-8884-ca830741bb38/) answer.

I have done all the required UI coding in Main Window, but it is not possible to connect it with the corresponding ViewModel (Placed it in another project and I am using its reference).

So my questions are, "Why can't I do this?", "How can I connect Window control with ViewModel?", "Should I use a UserControl instead?"

Comment: Why don't you use `UserControl` instead of `Window`?

Comment: Coz I did the coding before. Its a demo App in WPF for my learnings. I mensioned, If it is not possible at all then I'll try UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You`re trying to put one window inside the other and that`s not possible. Connecting View and ViewModel is much simpler but depends on your project structure.
You can set it in `Window` constructor, for example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window    
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The approach you`re trying to take just doesn`t work for `Windows` and is useful only when you put ViewModels themselves in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

To connect a viewmodel to a view you have to do the following in the xaml-code.

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The viewModel is the namespace.

```
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TestProject.ViewModel"
```

You shouldn't set the viewmodel in the codebehind of the view!

Comment: Does it really matter where to put VM initialization in this scenario? If it has parameterless constructor, putting it in constructor or XAML depends only on team coding conventions. Or am I missing something? And how will you solve situation where VM constructor has some parameters?

Comment: Sorry, i thought that this is mvvm :)